# Matching Odd or Even Numbers with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to have an if expressions inside a mod_rewrite file? The case I'm trying to solve is this:

Look for the 5 digit code in the URL
If the 5 digit code is even go to this url example: www.odd.com
else, go to another url example: www.even.com

I'm using regular expressions to get the 5 digits from the URL, but is it possible to add an expression to the rewrite?

Comment: Yes it is. What are your current rules. Put them in the question.

Comment: Did this work for you? Perhaps you could accept my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can include [expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html) in a `RewriteCond` but not needed for this.

The easiest way is just to check if the last digit is 1,3,5,7 or 9, or 0,2,4,6 or 8 in the regex, and have one rule for each.

Five digit even:

```
\d{4}[02468]
```

Five digit odd:

```
\d{4}[13579]
```